# android pendingintent sending duplicate data

Tags: android

My PendingIntent is working on time broadcast receiver. The problem is when I set my time and send first data it work successfully but when I send other data it again displays the first data and not the new one, below is my code.
All my *mServiceIntenyt* code is perfect but what is the error

```
mServiceIntent.putExtra("unique",lackmyData);
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(MessageActivity.this, 0, mServiceIntent, 0);
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pintent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not pass any *flag* then the `PendingIntent` ignores changes in extras when comparing `Intent`, causing the same old Intent to be spent again. You need to ask the PendingIntent to update the Intent as below:

```
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(MessageActivity.this,
                              0, mServiceIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Or in order to make sure your intent is unqiue based on extras, you may play with setData as below:

```
mServiceIntent.setData(Uri.parse(mServiceIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
```